# Why YOLO algorithm predicts B boxes for each grid cell S?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

In yolo each grid cell predicts multiple bounding boxes lets say in YOLOv1 it predicts B=2, what is the advantage as it only predicts class probabilities only once for each grid cell. If that so why not only use one bounding box...

Comment: As noted in the [YOLOv1 paper](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Redmon_You_Only_Look_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf): "*Each predictor gets better at predicting certain
sizes, aspect ratios, or classes of object, improving overall
recall*" $\Rightarrow$ During training, each of the Bounding boxes being predicted at the same cell. get specialized to certain shapes/ classes.

Comment: Each cell can contain multiple objects , and thus the `YOLO` algorithm should be able to predict so.